# Multiple Domains Name on one server with Nginx

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, virtualhost, varnish

I'm struggling to configure two different domains name on my dedicated server...

I've already one DN configured like this in the vhost DOMAIN_1.net.conf :

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:8080;

    server_name DOMAIN_1.net;
    access_log /home/DOMAIN_1/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/DOMAIN_1/logs/error.log;
    root /home/DOMAIN_1;

    client_max_body_size 30M;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite . /index.php last;
        }

    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

I've also have three others sub-domain of that domain configured the same way.

And I want to install an owncloud server on the domain name DOMAIN_2.ovh in vhost DOMAIN_2.ovh.conf :

```
upstream php-handler {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name DOMAIN_2.ovh;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  # enforce https
}

server {
        listen 8080;
        #listen 443 ssl;
        server_name DOMAIN_2.ovh;

        #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/owncloud.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/owncloud.key;

        error_log /home/DOMAIN_2.ovh/logs/error.log;
        access_log /home/DOMAIN_2.ovh/logs.access.log;

        # Path to the root of your installation
        #root /var/www/;
        root /home/DOMAIN_2.ovh/www/;

        client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

        index index.php;
        error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
        error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README) {
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
                rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
                rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

                rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
                rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

                rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

                try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        #        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
                fastcgi_pass php-handler;
        }

        # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
                expires 30d;
                # Optional: Don't log access to assets
                access_log off;
        }

}
```

But when I restart Nginx i've got this error :

**nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "DOMAIN_2.ovh" on 0.0.0.0:8080, ignored nginx.**

My nginx.conf file :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I've found a lot of subjects about this error but i can't solved it... If someone could help me, it will be a great christmas present ;) oh oh oh

Comment: You have two different `server` blocks with the same `server_name` and `listen` port.

Comment: You mean the two in DOMAIN_2.conf ? If I delete the first block and put the "return 301" line in the second block, it will solve my problem ?

Comment: I did it, and it works, thank you @MichaelHampton i've not the error anymore, but when i try to access the website I got this error : ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: That has nothing to do with this question!