# nginx: conflicting server name - again

Tags: nginx

*nginx* and *conflicting server name*. This comes up in a few questions but none of those match my case, see below.

On nginx startup I get messages like this

```
[warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "autoconfig.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
```

Everything *seems* to work as expected.

**My Configuration**

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://mail.myserver.de$request_uri;
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.*.conf;

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name mail.myserver.de mail01.myserver.de;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myserver.de.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myserver.de.key;

  [...]
}
```

The included files look like this:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.example.com.conf

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name autoconfig.example.com autodiscover.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com.key;

  [...]

  return 301 https://mail.myserver.de$request_uri;
}
```

**nginx error messages**

When nginx starts up, I get the following error messages for every included configuration:

```
2019/03/18 20:17:40 [warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "autoconfig.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2019/03/18 20:17:40 [warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "autodiscover.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2019/03/18 20:17:40 [warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "autoconfig.example.com" on [::]:443, ignored
2019/03/18 20:17:40 [warn] 1#1: conflicting server name "autodiscover.example.com" on [::]:443, ignored
```

**How I checked my config**

I triple checked my config for duplicated host names and haven't found any.   Multiple times I checked manually and with the following commands:

```
/ # nginx -T 2> /dev/null | grep example.com
# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.example.com.conf:
  server_name autoconfig.example.com autodiscover.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/autoconfig/example.com/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/autoconfig/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/autoconfig/example.com/ca.pem;

/ # grep -r example.com /etc/nginx/
/etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.example.com.conf:  server_name autoconfig.example.com autodiscover.example.com;
/etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.example.com.conf:  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/autoconfig/example.com/cert.pem;
/etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.example.com.conf:  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/autoconfig/example.com/privkey.pem;
/etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.example.com.conf:  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/autoconfig/example.com/ca.pem;
```

**My Questions**

*Why do these warnings show up in my case?*

*Have I missed a way to check for duplicated hosts in `server_name`?*

*How can I further debug this issue?*

*Can you think of any cases where this config might not work?*

*Is there a way to make my sense of order happy and get rid of these messages?*

**Related Questions**

The other questions I found do not match my problem. I do not mention a domain in two server blocks and all my blocks have server names specified.

- [Multiple Domains Name on one server with Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/654652/multiple-domains-name-on-one-server-with-nginx)
  Solution: two different server blocks with the same server_name
- [How to make NGINX redirect from http to https?](https://serverfault.com/questions/638327/how-to-make-nginx-redirect-from-http-to-https)
  Solution: two server blocks listening for SSL on the same port with the same server name
- [nginx: [warn] conflicting server name](https://serverfault.com/questions/928367/nginx-warn-conflicting-server-name)
  Solution: 2 server statements using the same server_name
- [Nginx conflicting server name for subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/708598/nginx-conflicting-server-name-for-subdomain)
  Solution: https blocks need server names specified too

Comment: Look for a symlink. My guess is you have symbolically linked something to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/autoconfig.example.com.conf` which is also being included.

Comment: Second guess, editor backup files in `..../sites-enabled/`

Comment: Unfortunately not. As I said: I checked multiple times and `nginx -T` does not overlook any hidden config file.

Comment: Why do you have this include at all? The config files specified would normally be included already by the existing include statement in the shipped nginx.conf.

Comment: Have the same problem. Funny thing is, that it's working though. I have two ssl subdomains on the same port and both respond correctly under their respective domains